# Hate to ask but does this script run on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Declare @Table table (RowNumber int, Increment int, Score int)

Insert into @Table 
values (1, 1, NULL), (2, 100000, NULL), (3, -1, NULL), 
       (4, 1, NULL), (5, 10, NULL), (6, -1, NULL), 
       (7, -100000, NULL), (8, -10, NULL)

Update @Table 
Set Score = B.Score
From  @Table A 
Join (Select RowNumber, Score = sum(Increment) over (Order By RowNumber) 
      from @Table) B on A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber

Select * from @Table
```

Returns

```
  RowNumber Increment       score
    1           1           1
    2           100000      100001
    3           -1          100000
    4           1           100001
    5           10          100011
    6           -1          100010
    7           -100000     10
    8           -10         0
```

Comment: Checked on DB with compatibility level = 100. It works fine.

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks for the quick response

Comment: So, you need code to run on SQL Server 2008? And you don't have access to an instance to try this out? Have you considered how badly any debugging is going to be if you let this situation continue? Trying to do all of your debugging and code-fixing via SO isn't going to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just updated your `UPDATE` statement ,Try it this gives expected result as you describe in your question

```
UPDATE @Table SET Score=(SELECT SUM(Increment) 
                          FROM  @Table B 
                          WHERE  b.RowNumber <= A.RowNumber)
FROM @Table A
```

Comment: plus 1 - Good alternative.  Never even considered it.  I just had a user who said the script provided does not run on 2008

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the original question is: No.

This query doesn't run on SQL Server 2008.

Cumulative `SUM` was implemented only in SQL Server 2012. The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause for the `SUM`.

```
sum(SomeColumn) over (Order By SomeColumn)
```

You will get this cryptic error message:

> Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
>
> The Parallel Data Warehouse
> (PDW) features are not enabled.

---

It will run on SQL Server 2012+ even with compatibility level set to SQL Server 2008 (100).

Comment: plus 1:  Thank you for your COMPLETE response.  However, I feel guilty deselecting JaydipJ's answer.  I trust you'll understand.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I thought that enough to check scripts with compatibility level equal to SQL Sever version.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, no problem. It is totally up to you to decide what answer was most helpful for you.